# Prevent applications from adding to start screen on install

Tags: shortcuts, windows-8, start-screen

On a Windows 8 machine, after installing Visual Studio, Office, SQL Server, VLC etc... the start screen is a mass clutter of unneeded shortcuts such as readme, shortcuts to homepages, various tools etc...
Is there a setting, or something, which prevents setup from adding all the new application shortcuts to the start screen? I still want them listed in the All Apps so I can search, and add the applications I need.

Comment: Why not just organize it, and put the stuff you don't want to see at the end?

Comment: @soandos why organize, when you could just NOT HAVE IT THERE?

Comment: That is what I'm doing atm, but I was wondering if this can be avoided. Just because I can do it does not mean that one should not look for better ways to do it, does it? ;)

Comment: I suspect that this is a function of the installer and there is nothing that you can do on the system to stop it for every app. The people writing the installers will need to start making it a checkbox option. Many installs are written this way already.

Comment: Another way MS is attempting to force users to use the start screen, its a brave new world in Windows 8.

Comment: It is not an MS decision. It is a decision by the software vendor.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot as it is the program itself who determines what gets installed in the "start menu". Just as on previous versions of windows, you have no influence over this as it is all legacy code.

I do have a suggestion however but it is not perfect.

go to your start menu folder: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and change the permissions of it so that the system can no longer write to the folder. That way nothing will get added. Have not tried this but should work. The negative point is that NO icons will be added, so not even the one for your app.

If this is not a solution, you can always just manage your start screen in that same folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to legacy installers that are not aware of how to "feature" only application icons onto the new Start Screen, and it's likely new applications will make better use of this feature in future.

There is no way to selectively stop icons being created (except for possibly stopping *all* of them), however you can remove icons from the main screen by right-clicking them and clicking the Unpin from Start button at the bottom.

They'll still be available in the All Apps screen or when searching, much like they were nestled away in folders in the old Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have installed some applications in one user and i found all shortcuts are added perfectly. But when i was signed in as a new user (this is the first time i was signed in to the pc), no shortcuts which shortcuts were added to the startmenu for previous installations are not displaying for this user.
                  In this same case if i signed in as a user which is already once signed in to the pc before done the installations.