# Can you stop desktop shortcuts being added to the start screen automatically?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent applications from adding to start screen on install](https://superuser.com/questions/468243/prevent-applications-from-adding-to-start-screen-on-install)

As I install new things (Visual Studio for example) I'm getting every tool, sdk, app related to my installs appearing on the Start Menu.

This is the most irritating feature I've found so far. Installing VS2010 - 2012 with SP1 and Windows Phone dev tools resulted in 2 pages worth of new icons that I had to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's currently any way to do this.

If you'd like to quickly remove tiles on the start screen, right-click all of the tiles you'd like to unpin and select "unpin."